# Scaling down a gif using pyglet

Tags: python, python-2.7, scaling, gif, pyglet

I am currently trying to make a simple image viewers that lets me view images or gifs. I've done most of the work and it's coming out how I'd like it, but I'd also like to be able to view gifs that are too big for my screen. I have a normal 1080p monitor, but the images are 1900x1300, which I understand is an odd image size for gifs. Problem is, pyglet has no obvious way to scale down gifs when drawing them. I'm using sprites, but scaling down the sprite merely returns an error, as the image itself hasn't actually changed, and is still 1900x1300.

What I need is a method to take a gif file, scale it down by 1/2, and render that gif using pyglet. I could probably use other libraries, but I'm trying to keep the project small.

Thanks!

Comment: I haven't used pyglet in a long time, but the dox indicates that you can scale pretty easily (and in fact, I think you could get the width of your window and scale by that to get poor mans full screen).  Can you include the snippet of code you're using to scale the sprite (and the error message / stack trace?)

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the code. It's all on my [github](https://github.com/nicktaber/Apollo/blob/master/Apollo.py). The problem isn't scaling the sprite though, that just uses sprite.scale: the problem lies in the gif no longer fitting in the sprite once you scale the sprite.